# Problem with arrows pointing in the wrong direction

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm new to TeX and the TiKz library and I'm currently working on creating an image of an inclined plane with an arrow pointing from a text point to the inclined part of the plane. However, I'm encountering some difficulties and the code doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\draw [thick] (0,0) -- (6,0) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, rotate around={-27:(0,3)}, shift={(0,3.25)}] (0.5,-0.25) rectangle (1,0.25);
\draw [<->, dashed] (-0.25,-0) -- (-0.25,3);
\node [left] at (-0.25,1.5) {$h$};

% Draw a horizontal line on the base of the plane
\draw [ultra thick] (6,0) -- (10,0);

% Add the label "Rough horizontal plane" below the line
\node [below] at (8,-0.7) {Rough horizontal plane};

% Draw an arrow from the label pointing to the line
\draw [->, thick] (8,-0.8) -- (8,0);

% Add the label "Smooth inclined plane" rotated like the inclined plane
\node [rotate=-27] at (4,2.5) {Smooth inclined plane};

% Calculate the coordinates of the hypotenuse of the triangle
\coordinate (A) at (6,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,3);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
\coordinate (H) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);

% Calculate the intersection point between the arrow and the hypotenuse
\coordinate (I) at ($(4,2.5)!(H)!(6,0)$);

% Draw an arrow from the label pointing to the hypotenuse of the triangle
\draw [->, thick] (4,2.5) -- (I);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, I have attached an image of the current output for reference.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving the issue and improving the image. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for the code, image and description of the issue you are facing. If possible, could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` - it is just helpful so we do not need to guess what class/packages and can copy and paste your code. Your code is easy to put in `standalone` or `article` so someone should be able to answer as-is but is good for future questions :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I have implemented the requested changes and hope that the updated version meets your expectations. @JamesT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible adjustements in your code to make it more efficient and the drawing looking better, but you asked for one thing, here it is.

I suggest to place a point H on line AB and then place the node at the right place (1cm and at right angle from H).

[image: arrows]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\draw [thick] (0,0) -- (6,0) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, rotate around={-27:(0,3)}, shift={(0,3.25)}] (0.5,-0.25) rectangle (1,0.25);
\draw [<->, dashed] (-0.25,-0) -- (-0.25,3);
\node [left] at (-0.25,1.5) {$h$};

% Draw a horizontal line on the base of the plane
\draw [ultra thick] (6,0) -- (10,0);

% Add the label "Rough horizontal plane" below the line
\node [below] at (8,-0.7) {Rough horizontal plane};

% Draw an arrow from the label pointing to the line
\draw [->, thick] (8,-0.8) -- (8,0);

\coordinate (A) at (6,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,3);
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);

% Put H on the middle of line AB
\coordinate (H) at ($(B)!0.5!(A)$);

% Add the label "Smooth inclined plane" rotated like the inclined plane and at 1 cm and at right angle from H
\node [rotate=-27,inner sep=1pt] (I) at ($ (H)!1cm!-90:(B) $) {Smooth inclined plane};

% Draw an arrow from the label pointing to the hypotenuse of the triangle
\draw [->, thick] (I) -- (H);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand that I mentioned being new to using TeX and the TiKz library, so it will take me some time to improve. However, I wanted to express my gratitude for providing the solution. Thank you very much. @SebGlav

Comment: You're very welcome. Improving a code needs time and patience. We all began where you stand. Keep up the good work.